Blue Goo and Firetrucks: Memories of a forgotten Children's TV show. Ideas?
During a recent conversation with a friend of mine, the topic somehow changed from the current Australian/China trade agreements, to what it would be like to own a fire truck. So yeah, we're mature.
The moment this sudden (and rather unexplainable) swing took place, a dying memory flickered into my consciousness, taking me back to my childhood: I was in front of the TV, fascinated by a strange kids show... 
It's name escapes me, as does the majority of the plot, but I clearly remember that the main characters - a small band of men and women - drove a firetruck. Nothing strange about that, no, but they were a part of a dedicated band of scientists (maybe?) that used this firetruck as a means to spray a special substance they called "Blue goo/goop" onto scary monster-like creatures that popped up around the city in a bid to destroy them.
One particular scene I recall involved a dude in a fireman's jacket spraying this blue goo at a row of tiny monsters, but the few remaining critters rapidly multiplied to fill the void. Another vivid memory was of a dude taking a drink from a water fountain and growing a large black tail in the process, much to the disbelief of his nearby friend.
From the way it was drawn, it could have been produced no sooner than 2006, but no later than the early 1990's. I was in Australia at the time of viewing. 
It annoys me so much that I can't for the life of me remember more, or at most the name of this silly kids series! I crave much to relive the nostalgia of watching various monsters being washed away by torrents of blue goo [sighs defeatedly]. Any ideas?

Do you mean this, by any chance (the animated Evolution series)?

No, of course they mean http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49605/movie-with-lots-of-different-monsters-with-orange-goop/49609#49609 ;)

@walt but you already know this is a dupe, so dupe close it already.

@Walt, yes, yes indeed :). Thanks to you, I can now retire happily to my lounge-room for the rest of my adult life, content in the knowledge this animation is real and that I did not spend a year of my childhood simply staring at a broken television set imagining up programs that didn't exist. Take that non-believing family/friends/medical practitioners, I am sane after all!

Glad you found it (and your peace of mind)! :) @cde Done, just wanted to make sure first. (I can't dupe close TV ID myself, BTW, just Movie ID.)
